# jQuery - How to print dynamically empty table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I think it's something with the string adding;

I've also tried:

```
var column = $("<td></td>")
```

instead of:

```
var column = $("<td>")
```

etc

and it's always the same result on the HTML : "[object Object]"

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
    createTable(8); 
});


function createTableColumn() {
    var column = $("<td>");

    return column;
}

function createTableRow(gameBoardSize) {
    var columns = "";
    var row;

    for(counter = 0; counter < gameBoardSize; counter++) {
        columns = columns + createTableColumn();
    }

    row = $("<tr>").append(columns);
    return row;

}

function createTable(gameBoardSize) {

    var rows = "";

    for(counter = 0; counter < gameBoardSize; counter++) {
        rows += createTableRow(gameBoardSize);
    }


    $("#gameboard-table").append(rows);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is for concatenating strings, not jQuery objects.

Just append directly to the jQuery objects:

```
function createTableRow(gameBoardSize) {
    var row = $("<tr>");
    for(var counter = 0; counter < gameBoardSize; counter++) {
        row.append(createTableColumn());
    }
    return row;
}

function createTable(gameBoardSize) {
    for(var counter = 0; counter < gameBoardSize; counter++) {
        $("#gameboard-table").append(createTableRow(gameBoardSize));
    }
}
```

Make sure you use local variables for loop counters. Otherwise, the `for` loop in `createTableRow` updates the counter in `createTable`, which causes that loop to end prematurely.

Comment: Thanks!! But I get only one row with eight columns with this code, what am I missing?

Comment: You need to use the `var` keyword on the `counter` variable so it will be local to each function.

Answer (score 2):

You are accidentally performing a string concatenation operation with `+= createTableRow...`. Change rows to an array and use push instead

```
var rows = [];
for(counter = 0; counter < gameBoardSize; counter++) {
    rows.push(createTableRow(gameBoardSize));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
    createTable(8);
  var i=0;
  $('td').each(function(){
      i++;
    $(this).text(i);
  });
});

function createTable(number){
    for(var count = 0;count<number;count++){
        $('#gameboard-table').append('<tr>');
        $('tr').append('<td>');  
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="gameboard-table"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

just string concatenation and one append.

```
function createTable(rowsCount, columnsCount) {
    var rows = "";
    var cell = "";
    var table = $("<table />")
    for (var i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++) {
        cell += "<td></td>";
    }
     for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
         rows += "<tr>" + cell + "</tr>";
     }
     table.append(rows);
         return table;
}
```